# how to delete string from a particular text to end of line?

Tags: awk, sed

For example,

if there is:

```
hello(abcdef) = 3
good(adss) = 5
```

then I have to replace these into:

```
hello
good
```

Thus I need to delete each line from '(' to right '\n' and replate these into '\n'

Is is possible by using sed or awk?

Comment: Please always show your efforts in your posts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '{sub(/\(.*/,"")} 1'   Input_file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/(.*//'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '(' '{ print $1 }' file
```

Using `cut`:

```
cut -d '(' -f 1 file
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/(.*//' file
```